# Laravel: Maatwebsite 3.1 using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

We upgraded the laravel version of our project, some of the packages has been depreciated(maatwebsite) so we need to upgrade to latest version and recode the export but we having an error.

To give a short background. Below is the layout.

[image]

The user should select the date, type and customer/s befure clicking the button. In this part we used the jquery/ajax

**Ajax**

```
if ( $('#sale-journal-export-csv').length > 0 ) {
            $('#sale-journal-export-csv').submit(function(e){
                $("input[name='customer_id[]']").remove();
                $("input[name='csv_default']").remove();
                var form = this;  
                var rows_selected = $('#get-customers-export-csv').DataTable().column(2).checkboxes.selected();
            // Iterate over all selected checkboxes
                $.each(rows_selected, function(index, rowId){
               // Create a hidden element 
                        $(form).append(
                           $('<input>')
                              .attr('type', 'hidden')
                              .attr('name', 'customer_id[]')
                              .val(rowId)   
                        );
                });
                var formData = $(form).serialize();
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                })
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/reports/sales-journal/exportCSV',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: formData,
                    xhrFields:{
                        responseType: 'blob'
                    },
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $('.export-csv-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        $('.loader').show();
                        var span = document.createElement("span");
                        span.innerHTML = '<span class="loading-animation">LOADING...</span>';
                        swal({
                            content: span,
                            icon: "warning",
                            buttons: false,
                            closeOnClickOutside: false
                        });
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response) {
                            let src = window.URL.createObjectURL(response);
                        }
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                         $('.export-csv-button').removeAttr('disabled');
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });
        }
```

**Controller**

```
public function exportCSV(Request $request)
    {
        $data                                               = $request->all();
        $data['csv_name']                                   = date('YmdHis-').'sale-journal';
        return new SaleJournalExport($data);
        // return (new SaleJournalExport($data))->download('sales-journal.csv');
        // return Excel::download(new SaleJournalExport($data), 'sales-journal.csv', \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::CSV);


    }
```

**SaleJournalExport Controller**

```
function __construct($data) {
    $output = [];

    $title = ['SALES JOURNAL'];
    
    $output[] = array_values($title);

    $data['company_name']    = UserModel::getCompanyDetails(Auth::user()->company_id);
    if(isset($data['csv_default'])){
        $data['start_date']      = $data['company_name']->accounting_period_start;
        $data['end_date']        = $data['company_name']->accounting_period_end;
        $data['customers']       = CustomerModel::getActiveCustomers();
        $sales                   = SaleJournalModel::getSalesByToday($data['company_name']);

    }else{
        $sales                   = SaleJournalModel::generalFilterAll($data);
    }

    $title6                      = [$data['company_name']->company_name];
    $output[]                    = array_values($title6);
    $date = 
      [
        date('F d, Y', strtotime($data['start_date'])). ' to ' .date('F d, Y', strtotime($data['end_date'])),
      ];
      
      $output[] = array_values($date);
   
    $space = 
    [
        ''
    ];
    $output[] = array_values($space);

    // DETAILS HEADER
    $header1 = 
    [
        "SI/OR No.","Sales Date","Document Reference","Customer","Status","Sales Amount","VAT Amount","Net of VAT","WHT Amount","Amount Due"
    ];

    $output[] = array_values($header1);

        if ($sales){
            foreach($sales as $index => $sale){
                $number                      = ($sale->sale_tag == '0') ? 'SI-'.$sale->number : 'OR-'.$sale->number;
                $table1[] = 
                [ 
                    $sale->number,
                    date('M d, Y',strtotime($sale->date_delivered)),
                    $sale->document_reference,
                    GlobalModel::getSingleDataTable('customers',$sale->customer_id)->name,
                    $this->checkStatus($sale->status),
                    ($sale->total_vat + $sale->total_net_of_vat),
                    $sale->total_vat,
                    $sale->total_net_of_vat,
                    $sale->total_wht,
                    $sale->total_amount_due
                              
                ];
                
            }
        } else {
            $table1[] = 
                [   
                    "",
                    "",
                    "",
                    "",
                    "",
                    "",
                    "",
                    "",
                    "",
                    "",
                ];
        }

        $output[]   = array_values($table1);

        $space = 
        [
            '',
            '',
            '',
            '',
            '',
            '',
            '',
            '',
            '',
            '',
        ];

        $output[]   = array_values($space);

        $footer = [];
        if ($sales){
                $footer = 
                [
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    "",
                    'Grand Total',
                    // $sales->whereNotIn('status_id',[13])->sum('total_amount'),
                    // $sales->whereNotIn('status_id',[13])->sum('discount'),
                    // $sales->whereNotIn('status_id',[13])->sum('vat_amount'),
                    // $sales->whereNotIn('status_id',[13])->sum('amount_due'),
                ];
        }else{
            $footer = 
            [
                '',
                '',
                '',
                '',
                '',
                '',
                '',
                '',
                '',
            ];
        }
        
       

        $output[]   = array_values($footer);
      
        $this->collection = collect($output);
 
}

public function collection()
{
    return $this->collection;
}
```

As you can see from the picture above in SaleJournalExport CSV, we manipulated the data then returned the value as collections.

We encountered an error "`The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), \"object\" given.`".

We already tried what we have search in the internet but it did not worked.

Question: How do I export to csv using jquery/ajax?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figured it out. What I did is

```
var binaryData = [];
binaryData.push(response);
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, {type: "application/zip"}))
link.download = 'sales-journal.csv';
link.click();
```